# IDisposable and Task.WaitAll waiting on itself

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, idisposable

I have a class that spawns several worker tasks using `Task.Run` and putting a reference to these Tasks in a collection. Furthermore this class implements `IDisposable` in order to clean up. In the implementation of `Dispose()` I use `Task.WaitAll(_listOfTasks)` to wait for all workers to finish.

Now it can happen, that the call to `Dispose()` is coming from one of those worker tasks which will obviously result in a deadlock since the `WaitAll` is waiting on itself.

Is there a pattern or recommended way to work around this situation?
Or are there other ways to make sure that all running Tasks are completed when the class is being disposed?

```
public class Loader : IDisposable
{

    private readonly IList<Task> _runningTasks = new List<Task>();

    public Loader()
    {
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Task.WaitAll(_runningTasks.ToArray());
    } 

    public void StartLoadAsync()
    {
        var task = Task.Run(() => DoSomeWork());

        _runningTasks.Add(task);         
    }

    void DoSomeWork()
    {
        // after doing some actual work here, call Dispose() in certain cases
        if (SomeCondition)
        {
            Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldnt be waiting for tasks in `Dispose()`. This method is for disposing

Comment: What's the reasoning behind implementing `IDisposable` here? You aren't working with unmanaged resources and using `Dispose` to wait for anything at all is extremely wrong

Comment: ok, lets assume i would not use `IDisposable` and instead call the function `CleanUp()`. How could the problem be solved then?

Comment: Do something like `async Task CleanUpAsync() => await Task.WhenAll(_runningTasks.ToArray());`

Comment: The pattern is **not** to control the disposing from within a task that is subjected to the disposal.  There is a reason why CancellationToken is separated from CancellationTokenSource.

Comment: @clamp - It would be ideal to see how you are creating all of these tasks. What's the source? Can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: Cancel if necessary to tell the tasks that their results are not going to be required but otherwise just ignore them - they'll finish/cancel when they can. I'm also a bit worried about this "unknown/circular" ownership relationship between this `IDisposable` and the tasks it "owns".

Comment: The question is too broad. But: a) don't wait in `Dispose()`, b) if you feel you need to delay clean up until all tasks have run, wait asynchronously for them to finish, then clean up. If you want to make that an async cleanup method, or just don't call the clean up until an explicit call to `WhenAll()` completes asynchronously, either is fine. But the fundamental issue here is your mixing of async and non-async. That will (nearly) always get you into trouble, and should certainly be avoided in this case.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways how the `IDisposable` interface is used in the .NET ecosystem. I want to show to two of them which are especially relevant in a multi-threaded/asynchronous usage.

### Reactive Extensions

When subscribing to an observable, an `IDisposable` object is return. Here the interface serves as a cancellation trigger. There is no thread affinity and it can be called at any time. The implementation promises best effort cancellation, but gives no guarantees when the cancellation will finally happen. This implies that after the call of `Dispose` the subscription maybe still active for a while.

### `IAsyncEnumerator`

In the upcoming `IAsyncEnumerable` interface you will be able to pass a cancellation token when retrieving the enumerator. The enumerator implements `IAsyncDisposable` and should be disposed. The enumerator is not require to be thread safe, i.e., it is not allowed to call `DisposeAsync` while a call to another interface method or a returned task are still running. If you want to stop the enumeration you have to utilize the cancellation token.

### Conclusion

It is important to distinguish between cancellation and resource clean up. In your case you could also use a cancellation token. Since you already have everything build around a method call you could alternatively add a `Cancel` method. If you need to now when your loader actually terminates, you can implement the `IAsyncDisposable` interface:

```
public void Cancel() => ...;
public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
{
    // Cancel();
    await Task.WhenAll(_runningTasks.ToArray());
}
```

If you want, you can call `Cancel` from the the `DisposeAsync` method. I'm not sure if there are any best practice about that. I'd tend to not call `Cancel` there, because it gives you or your API users more possibilities. Note, that the `IAsyncDisposable` interface will only come with netstandard 2.1. That should not stop you, however, to use that pattern right now.